# How get the first matching element from stream filter() in JAVA 11?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

How get the first matching element from stream filter() in JAVA 11?

```
List<Address> addresses = List.of(
    new Address(1, "Office", "AAAAA"), new Address(2, "Correspondence", "BBBBB"),
    new Address(3, "Residence", "CCCC"), new Address(4, "Next Door", "DDDD"));
```

How to retrieve the first matching address based on the priorities?

```
addresses.stream().filter(a->a.getType().equals("Residence")).findAny()
  .orElseGet(() -> addresses.stream().filter(a->a.getType()
       .equals("Correspondence")).findAny()
            .orElseGet(()->addresses.stream().filter(a->a.getType()
               .equals("Correspondence")).findAny().orElseGet(null)));
```

How to simplify the above code to get the `Address` based on it's `Type`?

If the `Residence` type is available in the List then `return Address`, else next priorities are followed `Correspondence`, `Office`, and `Next Door`.

What is the best way to do it in `STREAM`?

Comment: Create a map (`Map<Type,Prority>`)for address type with prority order (1,2,3...) and using stream sort by priorty order and findFirst

Comment: And recommend to use enum for Address type. Then you can use ordinal or value of enum for priority also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list of the types, in order of desired precedence, to both filter the stream and as the basis of a comparator you use with [`min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min(java.util.Comparator)) on the stream:

```
List<String> types = List.of("Residence", "Correspondance", "Office", "Next Door");

addresses.stream()
    .filter(a -> types.contains(a.getType()))
    .min(comparingInt(a -> types.indexOf(a.getType())));
```

——

You would typically use a constant for the list so it didn’t need to be created every time.

```
private static final List<String> ADDRESS_TYPES = List.of("Residence", "Correspondance", "Office", "Next Door");
```

——-

p.s "Correspondence" is spelled ...ence, not ...ance

Comment: Just a side note for readers - there is a crucial decision abstracted in the implementation, it needs both a check of presence `.contains` and `indexOf` an element. One might not always prefer a `List` in that case.

Comment: @Naman what better choice is there than a (static) list?

Comment: Could be based around the nature of the data. (how long is the static list, does it just comprise of `String` or other plain objects). But yeah an alternate example to quote could have been a `Map` which facilitates `contains` over the `keySet` and `get` for the priority. All of that is worth it when someone actually needs to go deeper into that abstracted implementation layer of performing a contains and getting the index of the element.

Comment: @Naman simple is best. How many address types do you think there are? “Very few” is the answer. A map would be more complicated, and not contain any more actual data than the list, whose element position is the priority. And it would perform slower! Although in the general case the `contains()` method of a `List` has O(n) time complexity, the list is so short its `contains()` will perform in constant time and will out-perform that of the `containsKey()` method of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian for the answer. Thanks @Holger, `.min()` requires `Comparator`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int priority(Address addr) {
      switch (addr.getType())
        case "Residence":
            return 1;
        case "Correspondance":
            return 2;
        case "Office":
            return 3;
        case "Next Door":
            return 4;
        default:
            return 5;
      }
}

private Optional<Address> bestAddress(List<Address> addresses) {
    return
       addresses.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(this::priority));
}
```

Edited as per comment. Thanks.

Comment: `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::priority)).findFirst()` is a good candidate for `.min(Comparator)`